# Why Code listing of pocketsphinx isn't working in my ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I installed pocketsphinx according to this [link.](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) In this tutorial, there is a code of listing.
the code is:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ps_decoder_t *ps;
    cmd_ln_t *config;
    FILE *fh;
    char const *hyp, *uttid;
    int16 buf[512];
    int rv;
    int32 score;

    config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                 "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                 "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                 "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                 NULL);
    if (config == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create config object, see log for details\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ps = ps_init(config);
    if (ps == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create recognizer, see log for details\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fh = fopen("goforward.raw", "rb");
    if (fh == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file goforward.raw\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rv = ps_start_utt(ps);

    while (!feof(fh)) {
        size_t nsamp;
        nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
        rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
    }

    rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
    hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
    printf("Recognized: %s\n", hyp);

    fclose(fh);
    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);

    return 0;
}
```

In this tutorial, there is a line about MODELDIR which is:

> The MODELDIR macro is defined on the GCC command-line by using
>   pkg-config to obtain the modeldir variable from PocketSphinx
>   configuration.

In this code, modeldir variable which I get by running this command

```
 abnormal@abnormal:~$ pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx
/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model
```

So I edited the code in the following way:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ps_decoder_t *ps;
    cmd_ln_t *config;
    FILE *fh;
    char const *hyp, *uttid;
    int16 buf[512];
    int rv;
    int32 score;

    config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                         "-hmm",  "/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us",
                         "-lm",  "/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                         "-dict", "/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                         NULL);
    if (config == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create config object, see log for details\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ps = ps_init(config);
    if (ps == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create recognizer, see log for details\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fh = fopen("goforward.raw", "rb");
    if (fh == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file goforward.raw\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rv = ps_start_utt(ps);

    while (!feof(fh))
    {
        size_t nsamp;
        nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
        rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
    }

    rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
    hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
    printf("Recognized: %s\n", hyp);

    fclose(fh);
    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);

    return 0;
}
```

then I compile and run the code. But I got error:

```
abnormal@abnormal:~$ cd Desktop
abnormal@abnormal:~/Desktop$ gcc -c Untitled1.c -o sss.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase`
abnormal@abnormal:~/Desktop$ ./sss.o
bash: ./sss.o: Permission denied
```

what did i do wrong? what sholud I do now? I am using ubuntu 14,04 LTS. Please help.

Comment: `.o` files aren't executables, and wouldn't have the execute bit set. they're just object files, and by themselves are useless until you use a linker to produce an actual executable.

Comment: Oh! thanks.. Now I get it...